# Beautiful Soup, prettified html to txt, get encoding error

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to save a prettified print of a html file, to a txt file, but get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prettyhtmlfiles.py", line 16, in <module>
    file.write(soup.prettify())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbb' in position 8532: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I get around this problem?

The code I have:

```
import urllib2
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = "/home/sveisa/S141test/ayuki.html"
with open(url, 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open('/home/sveisa/S141test/ayuki.html').read())

print(soup.prettify())


file = open("newfile.txt", "w")

file.write(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: Try `file.write(soup.prettify().decode('utf-8'))`

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It should work.

```
print >> file, (soup.prettify().encode('utf-8'))
```