# Python webscraping - NoneObeject Failure - broken HTML?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Ive got a problem with my parsing script in python. Ive tried it already at another page (yahoo-Finance) and it worked fine. On morningstar nevertheless its not working.
I get the Error in the terminal "NoneObject" of the table variable. I guess it has to do with the structure of the moriningstar site, but iḿ not sure. Maybey somneone can tell me what went wrong.
Or is it not possible because of the sitestructure of the Morningstar site to use my simple script?

A simple csv export direct from morningstar is not a solution because I would like to use the script for other sites which dont have this functionality.

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html

url = 'http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=SBUX&region=USA&culture=en_US'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'r_table1 text2'})

print table.prettify() #debugging

list_of_rows = []
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
   list_of_cells =[]

   for cell in row.findAll(['th','td']):
        text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
        list_of_cells.append(text)
   list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)
print list_of_rows #debugging

outfile = open("./test.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table is *dynamically loaded* with a separate XHR call to an endpoint which would return `JSONP` response. Simulate that request, extract the JSON string from the JSONP response, load it with `json`, extract the HTML from the `componentData` key and load with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import json
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# make a request
url = 'http://financials.morningstar.com/financials/getFinancePart.html?&callback=jsonp1450279445504&t=XNAS:SBUX&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&order=asc&_=1450279445578'
response = requests.get(url)

# extract the HTML under the "componentData"
data = json.loads(re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z_0-9\.]*\()|(\);?$)', '', response.content))["componentData"]

# parse HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'r_table1 text2'})
print(table.prettify())
```

Comment: Hello alecxe,
thanks a lot for your advice. It worked fine. Got just a problem with the csv output, but I think i can fix it by myself.
Antoher question: Whats the "syntax" for such an JSON request?
Best regards

Comment: @CarstenDiPietrangelo this is called [`JSONP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) - basically a json with a callback.

Comment: I tried to figure out how I get this URL where "jsonp" is included but cant make it. Could you give some more explanation. Sorry.

Comment: @CarstenDiPietrangelo you would see that if you would print out the `response.content`.

Comment: I printed it out and then it showed me "jsonp1450279445504" but it only works if I use your url. If I use mine from OP I get a lot of javaScript. 

i found following passage in the jscript. But how exactly I get the "jsonp1450279445504"? And the term at the end of the url "1450279445578"?

-- Java Code -- var urlstr = "//financials.morningstar.com/financials/getFinancePart.html?&callback=?&t=XNAS:SBUX&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&order="+orderby;

Comment: I get this error when executing your code: `print(table.prettify())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2014' in position 5851: ordinal not in range(128)' because of the `prettify`

Comment: @aDoN may be this is your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818815/prettify-error-using-python-2-7

Comment: @aDoN or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24674987/beautiful-soup-prettified-html-to-txt-get-encoding-error